# How to convert string of array to array of string?

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have this kind of array:

```py
'[[00487-9904-01, 00487-9904-25], [00487-9901-30]]'
```

How can I convert it to array of strings

```py
[["00487-9904-01", "00487-9904-25"], ["00487-9901-30"]]
```

I tried ast.literal_eval and json.loads,  because inside the array,  00487-9904-01 is neither a string or a number,  neither of these two methods works.

Comment: Where are you getting this data from?  Why is it not a JSON string to begin with?

Comment: Put some quotes around the values and then do the `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: @rdas Wouldn't you need to parse it to quote them? I'm assuming OP doesn't control the input data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `yaml` module:

```py
import yaml

s = '[[00487-9904-01, 00487-9904-25], [00487-9901-30]]'
yaml.safe_load(s)
```

output: `[['00487-9904-01', '00487-9904-25'], ['00487-9901-30']]`

*NB. `ast.literal_eval` wouldn't work as the strings are not quoted*